# Time Machine Backup is creating full size backups and filling my harddrives faster than usual

Tags: time

I have had many 1TB hard drives and have used TMB since its inception.  but recently i bought a brand new HD and set it up.. after only a few back ups, i got an error message saying there was no space on my harddrive.. i used omnidsic sweeper to check out my disc to find that it was saying it had over 4TB of stuff on it!? I know thats not remotely possible,. but im curious why it would say that and more over, why is TMB taking full size back ups? i checked and there is only 3 on the drive.  i have backed my puters up for years on just 1TB.. any help? thanks in advance

Comment: Any ONE!? Any time machine knowledge out there?

Comment: Which drive did you replace - the one being backed up or the TMB drive? Erroneous usage readings on TMB volumes is somewhat usual for utilities like DiskSweeper because of the way Time Machine stores the backup data.

Comment: Its a brand new external drive.. i understand (i think) why omnidisc is confused, but my drive is still maxed out after only 3 backs ups..

Comment: Did you begin with a migrated backup or from scratch?

Comment: My computer was up an going already, 750gb hd in it. i then started using the brand new TMBU HD. Ran the app to set up the new TMBUHD, backed it up, and walah. (My laptop HD had about 650gb on it, so it was pretty full). After the 2nd or 3rd backup is when it started to say "NOT ENOUGH SPACE TO RUN TMBU".

Comment: I might be looking for things like sparseimage files or other large items that could be consuming the backup space during the normal TMBU sequence.